# C - Error print char with scanf_s in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, printf, scanf

First, my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int a;
   char b;

   printf("Insert number: ");
   scanf_s("%i",&a);
   getchar();

   printf("Insert character: ");
   scanf_s("%c",&b);

   printf("Number: %i\n",a);
   printf("Character: %c\n",b);

   getchar();
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

I use scanf_s but visual studio 2012 say error with scanf. Ok, no problem with int, but the problem is when i can use char.

Save the char in var but when i call printf this var, dont show anything, why?

I check this on linux and work perfectly.

Sorry my english :)

Comment: The code compiles and executes correctly for me with visual studio 2012.  Are you sure you've posted the correct code?  If you have, can you exit your question to note either the compiler or runtime error you see?  If you get a runtime error, please say what input you supply, what output you receive and what output you expected.

Comment: i don't have error code, the program is run normally but when i call printf function with var char, dont show the result.

screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/2Ncz0bf.png

Comment: I can reproduce this if I type 5[space][enter] for the number.  Are you typing anything before your number or between it and enter?

Comment: nop, only insert 1 number and 1 character (5[enter]c[enter])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You must specify the size of the input string or character in [scanf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).**

change

```
scanf_s("%c",&b);
```

to

```
scanf_s("%c", &b, 1);
```

Comment: THANKS! Work perfectly :)